# Adding metadata to express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, metadata, aop

Is there any way to add metadata to the routes in express? for example:

```
app.get("/some/route", function(req,res) {
// ...
}, { some: 'meta-data' });
```

I am looking at a sort of AOP approach to my node application so I want to proxy certain routes with authentication and/or logging. To do this I need to be able to assign some sort of hooking identifier to each route to indicate it should be proxied, so the AOP knows nothing about the individual methods and the methods know nothing about the AOP framework...

Then without getting too much off topic I would use something like hooker or some other proxying library to check through all routes where it has `some` and add a `thing` interceptor.

So anyway any best practice way to do the sort of thing mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost have it.  You can use the bind method to bind variables to a function call.

```
app.get("/some/route", function(req,res) {
  res.send(this.test);
}.bind({test:'<html><body>hello world</body></html>'}));
```

Comment: you evil genius, will go give it a try now as I would need to make sure I could somehow check if a route has that given variable bound.

Comment: Make sure you add the "this" to test when accessing it.  I missed that in the original post.

Comment: seems that its tricky to get access to that sort of metadata, so maybe I should just look at using middleware as that is basically what im wanting to do, just without explicitly binding the middleware in the route. That aside it is really useful to know that you can bind like that, and in the context of this question I guess that you have the answer.

Comment: Holy f...n GENIUS! What a brilliant hack!